# DropZonejs: Submit form without files

Tags: dropzone.js

I've successfully integrated dropzone.js inside an existing form. This form posts the attachments and other inputs like checkboxes, etc.

When I submit the form with attachments, all the inputs post properly. However, I want to make it possible for the user to submit the form without any attachments. Dropzone doesn't allow the form submission unless there is an attachment.

Does anybody know how I can override this default behavior and submit the dropzone.js form without any attachments? Thank you!

```
   $( document ).ready(function () {
    Dropzone.options.fileUpload = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form element

      // The configuration we've talked about above
      autoProcessQueue: false,
      uploadMultiple: true,
      parallelUploads: 50,
      maxFiles: 50,
      addRemoveLinks: true,
      clickable: "#clickable",
      previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
      acceptedFiles: "image/*,application/pdf, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template, application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12, application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12,text/rtf,text/plain,audio/*,video/*,.csv,.doc,.xls,.ppt,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,.pptx",



        // The setting up of the dropzone
      init: function() {
        var myDropzone = this;

        // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
        this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          myDropzone.processQueue();
        });

        // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
        // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
        this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
          // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
          // Hide the success button or the complete form.
        });
        this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
            window.location.replace(response.redirect);
            exit();
        });
        this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
          $("#notifications").before('<div class="alert alert-error" id="alert-error"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><i class="icon-exclamation-sign"></i> There is a problem with the files being uploaded. Please check the form below.</div>');
          exit();
        });

      }

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 24):

Use the following:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on("click", function (e) {

                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();

                    var form = $(this).closest('#dropzone-form');
                    if (form.valid() == true) { 
                        if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {                        
                            myDropzone.processQueue();  
                        } else {                       
                            myDropzone.uploadFiles([]); //send empty 
                        }                                    
                    }               
                });
```

Reference: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/418

Comment: I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined dropzone.js?body=1:1447 when submitting without files.  have you tested this?

Comment: apparently this requires a source code modification(see reference) to avoid the error I was getting.

Comment: @light24bulbs Glad you figured it out. That's what the reference is for, so you can get the whole context of the solution.

Comment: There is an open issue. Please upvote so this gets fixed. 
https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/687

Comment: `myDropzone.uploadFile([])` does not send request.

Answer (score 18):

You should check if there are files in the queue. If the queue is empty call directly dropzone.uploadFile(). This method requires you to pass in a file. As stated on [caniuse][1], the File constructor isn't supported on IE/Edge, so just use Blob API, as File API is based on that.

The formData.append() method used in dropzone.uploadFile() requires you to pass an object which implements the Blob interface. That's the reason why you cannot pass in a normal object.

dropzone version 5.2.0 requires the upload.chunked option

```
if (this.dropzone.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
    var blob = new Blob();
    blob.upload = { 'chunked': this.dropzone.defaultOptions.chunking };
    this.dropzone.uploadFile(blob);
} else {
    this.dropzone.processQueue();
}
```

Comment: This answer should be on top ! Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is only what worked for me. Here is the reference: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/687

Comment: Only solution that worked for me with version 5.7.0. All other answers are valid for version 4.x.

Comment: Thank you for your solution!
In case of undefined `defaultOptions`, you can also use `this.dropzone.options.chunking`.

Comment: I tried this way, but server side request not being sent with `this.dropzone.uploadFile(blob)`

Answer (score 16):

Depending on your situation you could simply submit the form:

```
if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {                        
   myDropzone.processQueue();  
} else {                       
   $("#my_form").submit();
}
```

Comment: @Limon check that your form is tagged with enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: You are right but I'd like to point out that you completely separate event handlers if you don't want a page reload but handle the server response in JavaScript. Dropzone fires several events before/during/after the submission which will not be triggered in your "else" case.

Comment: This assumes that you have a form on the page! Using `dzClosure.on('sending', function (data, xhr, formData)` can be supplied with Custom form content in which case unfortunately this method won't work.

Comment: Thank you this worked as I was using Dropzone.js  combined with an existing form. People who use it without an existing form should find another solution.

Answer (score 6):

The first approach is kind of too expensive for me, I would not like to dive into the source code and modify it,

If you happen to be like me , use this.

```
function submitMyFormWithData(url)
    {
        formData = new FormData();
        //formData.append('nameOfInputField', $('input[name="nameOfInputField"]').val() );

        $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                type: 'POST',

                success: function(data){
                alert(data);
                }
        });
    }
```

And in your dropzone script

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(e) {
                      // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
                      e.preventDefault();
                      e.stopPropagation();

                        if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0)
                        {                        
                                myDropzone.processQueue();  
                        } else {                 
                                submitMyFormWithData(ajaxURL);
                        }     

                    });
```

Comment: best solution for now since the blob method creates a file that you will need to deal with in server side no to upload it

Answer (score 4):

I tried Matija Grcic's answer and I got the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

And I didn't want to modify the dropzone source code, so I did the following:

```
        if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {                        
            myDropzone.processQueue();  
        } else {                       
            myDropzone.uploadFiles([{name:'nofiles'}]); //send empty 
        }
```

Note: I'm passing an object inside the array to the uploadFiles function.

Then I check server-side, if name != 'nofiles' do upload stuff.

Comment: @Agu.nice sollution . myDropzone.uploadFiles([{name:'nofiles'}]);  it helped me

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple, you stop the propagation ONLY if you have files to be submitted via Dropzone:

```
// First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // Stop the propagation ONLY if you have files to be submitted via Dropzone
  if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        myDropzone.processQueue();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used :

```
submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {  
  if(wrapperThis.files.length){
        error = `Please select a file`; 
    } else {
        wrapperThis.processQueue(); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on the fact that the other answers don't allow for an Ajax based solution where an actual HTML form isn't actually being used. Additionally you may want the *full form contents* submitted when sending the Files for upload as well.

As you'll see, my form occurs in a modal *outside* of any form tag. On completion, the modal is triggered to close.

(FYI getForm returns the form as an object and not directly related to the answer. Also assumes use of jQuery)

```
init: function() {
    var dzClosure = this;

    // When saving what are we doing?
    $('.saveBtn').off('click').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        if (dzClosure.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {
            dzClosure.processQueue();

            dzClosure.on('queuecomplete',function(){
                $('.modal:visible').modal('hide');
            })
        } else {
            var params = getForm();

            $.post(dzClosure.options.url,params,function(){
                $('.modal:visible').modal('hide');
            })
        }
    });

    dzClosure.on('sending', function (data, xhr, formData) {
        var extra = getForm();

        for (key in extra){
            formData.append(key,extra[key]);
        }
    });
```