# dropzone: submit button doesn't work when no file selected

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I have a dropzone form to upload files, included in a standard form with 2 input text, for which the behaviour of the submit button (id=submit-all) is governed by the following javascript part (in order to upload all files once the button is clicked):

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  uploadMultiple: true,
  init: function() {
    var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
        myDropzone = this; // closure
    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
    });
    this.on("queuecomplete", function (file) {
      if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
        location.href = 'write.php?final=y';
     }
    });
  }
};
```

When the button is clicked, all files are uploaded and processed as expected, and then the visitor is redirected to the page 'write.php?final=y' (congrats message).
However this script does not work when no file is selected: clicking the button has no effect at all.

Could anyone help me with this issue ?
Many thanks in advance for your replies !!

Comment: Why would you want the submit button to work when there are no files in dropzone?

Comment: @Martin: because the submit button triggers several things: upload and process pictures when some are selected, but also send a confirmation email and finally redirect to another page.

Comment: @martin: I forgot to mention that the form also includes 2 input text tags

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910571/dropzonejs-submit-form-without-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

queuecomplete is not emitted because there are no files

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  uploadMultiple: true,
  init: function() {
    var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all");
    myDropzone = this; // closure
    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (myDropzone.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
            location.href = 'write.php?final=y';
        }
        else {
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        }
    });
  }
};
```

there is also a way to manually emit event, just simple use

```
this.emit("signalname");
```

and the list of events

```
Dropzone.prototype.events = ["drop", "dragstart", "dragend", "dragenter", "dragover", "dragleave", "addedfile", "addedfiles", "removedfile", "thumbnail", "error", "errormultiple", "processing", "processingmultiple", "uploadprogress", "totaluploadprogress", "sending", "sendingmultiple", "success", "successmultiple", "canceled", "canceledmultiple", "complete", "completemultiple", "reset", "maxfilesexceeded", "maxfilesreached", "queuecomplete"];
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work: clicking the submit button has no effect wether some files are selected or not.

Comment: This works for me, check console log, maybe there is problem with locating your submit-all button

Comment: I get the following message from the console log: "Exception with thrown value: TypeError: this.getUploadingFiles is not a function. (In 'this.getUploadingFiles()', 'this.getUploadingFiles' is undefined)"

Comment: Works well. Thanks a lot Adam !