# How to upload a smaller version and the original image in DropZone.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, upload, dropzone.js

I looked at this thread:

https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/781

The issue is that it seems this would resize the original image and that would be the only image uploaded to the server?

I want to display the smaller version in my gallery to save bandwidth and the original when a user clicks on an image in the gallery to see it full size.

How could I upload both the smaller resized version and the original to my server?

(The images will be stored in a google cloud bucket when sent to my server and then queried from the cloud bucket on the client from there on)

Here's my current code which uploads the image to my server.

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {

    autoProcessQueue: false,
    paramName: "image",
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    maxFilesize: 5, // MB
    uploadMultiple: false,
    maxFiles: 1,

    init: function() {
        var myDropzone = this;
        url: '/upload'

        this.on("addedfile", function() {
            if (this.files[1] != null) {
                this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
            }
        });
        this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        });

        this.on("success", function(response) {
            localStorage.setItem("success_msg_local2", "Post Created. Reload Page");
            window.location.href = "screenshots/index";
        });

        this.on('error', function(file, response) {
            localStorage.setItem("error_msg_local", response);
            window.location.href = "upload";
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: No need for official/credible sources necessarily. Just want to get an answer that works.

Comment: I would recommend to upload the original image and generate the thumbnail/ the smaller version in your server application. This way the consistency of your data (every image has a thumbnail) does not depend on two different requests that could possibly fail individually. If you don't want to do this and you don't want to add a thumbnail library you could use dropzone.js "thumbnail" (fired after thumbnail creation) where you get the thumbnail  data URL as second parameter and you can upload/post it to the server

Comment: @RobinJ Just to make sure I understand: what is the benefit of creating the thumbnail on the server when I just save it to a google cloud bucket anyway ? Wouldn't it be better to save the RAM cost of creating the thumbnail on the server ? How can I control the size of the thumbnail ? Could you please post  a more detailed answer with some code ?

Comment: The benefit of creating the thumbnail in your server application: (in addition to the ones @enyo already mentioned) 1. You don't have to deal with the mapping of the thumbnail upload and the image upload(imagine a user uploads multiple images and thumbnails at the same size, you need to match each image to the thumbnail) 2. You don't need a thumbnail library that runs on client side (browser compatibility). You should be able to find an image library that matches your backend language/architecture easily as thumbnail generation is a pretty common task.

Comment: @RobinJ Currently trying jimp. Have most likely a syntax issue somewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328718/jimp-write-not-correct-syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropzone doesn't really offer anything in regards to that. You can probably try to copy the file in the `addedfile` event, add some flag to it (`myCopiedFile.isCopied = true;`) and add it again (with `this.addFile(copiedFile)`. Then you would need to make sure that the thumbnail isn't shown (by checking if the `.isCopied` flag is set), and only resize it, if the flag is set or not.

I agree with the point @robin-j made in the comment: this is something I would do on the server.

The advantages being:

1. The user needs to upload less bytes and saves bandwidth
2. You have more control when resizing (jpeg algorithms can be optimised to generate the smallest file size possible)
3. You don't run the risk of users doing something funny with the data (for example: they could write a simple script, that uploads two completely different images as thumbnail and original)

Comment: To do this, you will probably want to use [graphicsmagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) (or [imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)). Depending on your server language there are libraries you can use to easily use those services. If not, you can simply spawn a shell command to do the resizing.

Comment: @enoy All right ! Thank you for taking the time to pass by to help ^^